# pfSense OpenVPN clients routing

Tags: vpn, routing, openvpn, pfsense

We've setup OpenVPN using **pfSense 2.0.2**.

Local subnet is **192.168.1.0/24**, VPN clients are **10.0.1.0/24**

We also have another subnet **192.168.0.0/24** which is connected through **pfSense IPSec** as a **Site-To-Site** VPN.

OpenVPN clients are able to ping hosts on **192.168.1.0/24** subnet without any problems, but are unable to ping hosts on **192.168.0.0/24**.

pfSense itself is able to ping **192.168.0.0/24** clients from "**Diagnostics > Ping**" menu, but unable to do so from shell.

We need to enable OpenVPN clients to access hosts on 192.168.0.0./24 subnet.

Adding routes manually on OpenVPN clients doesn't help. We already tried:

```
route add 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.254
route add 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.254
route add 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.0.1.1
```

**UPD:** Still unresolved issue with traffic from 192.168.0.0 to 10.0.1.0... Although hosts from 10.0.1.0 are able to access hosts on 192.168.0.0 thanks to @chris-buechler answer

Answer (score 1):

You need two things. One, a push route on the OpenVPN server to send the clients a route. push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0" Then a second phase 2 with the local being 10.1.0.0/24 and remote 192.168.0.0/24, and vice versa on the remote end.

Comment: Almost! Now we are able to ping from 10.0.1.0/24 subnet hosts on 192.168.0.0/24 subnet, but not vice versa. Should we provide any configuration files?